# Entity returns error in MultiPartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, android-asynctask, multipartentity

I've tried following links but none of them helped to solve the issue.

> [HttpPost returning error when using MultipartEntityBuilder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480838/httppost-returning-error-when-using-multipartentitybuilder-in-android)
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803149/1226882

***Here's the code***

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Utility.AddProductWS);

MultipartEntityBuilder multipartBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

/* example for setting a HttpMultipartMode */
multipartBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

for (int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++) {

    multipartBuilder.addBinaryBody("images[]", newFile(photos.get(i).getImagePath());
}

multipartBuilder.addTextBody("username", username.toString());
multipartBuilder.addTextBody("accept_best_offer", String.valueOf(acceptOffer.isChecked() ? 1 : 0));
multipartBuilder.addTextBody("accept_trade", String.valueOf(acceptTrade.isChecked() ? 1 : 0));
multipartBuilder.addTextBody("product_price", etProductPrice.getText().toString());
multipartBuilder.addTextBody("product_description", etProductDescription.getText().toString());

HttpEntity httpEntity = multipartBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);  // Error line
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
Utility.showLog(TAG, EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```

**Error**

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of
>   type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; in class
>   Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; or its
>   superclasses (declaration of
>   'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter' appears in
>   /system/framework/ext.jar)

I am using **httpcore-4.4.1** and **httpmime-4.4.1** library files.

Comment: try to add post one file using `entityBuilder.addBinaryBody(IMAGE, file);` and check.

Comment: I tried the same and it doesnt work too :(

Comment: @MuhammadBabar any idea?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar Finally it worked!! It's a library problem. Thanks for looking the issue.

Comment: Glad to heard you're done :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally I've solved it.

***It's a library issue, it worked with 4.3.1 version.***

Here's the link to [download](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/) library files

Comment: @droid_dev: I have these versions but it doesn't work (same error like you):  compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.1') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.1') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }

Comment: Now try with okhttp library. It works without these library

Answer (score 3):

Try with theese versions, is working for me

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
```

Also you can read more [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66177408).

Answer (score 0):

multipartBuilder.addPart("images[]", fileBody);  fileBody convert into byteArray then you pass  because data travel in byte array

[Try to upload the image in php server but it could post. in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14027882/try-to-upload-the-image-in-php-server-but-it-could-post-in-android/14028835#14028835)