# Android Multipart Post upload, using light libraries

Tags: android, file-upload, httpclient, multipart

I'm need to upload media to a server (images, video, audio etcc..) this file are not bigger than 2GB.

Searching in S.O. I found many solutions, like this one (implemented this)--> [Post multipart request with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk/5220954#5220954)

But, it needs external libraries and when I attach to the project in ecplise and try to run the code, eclipse launches:

```
[2015-09-10 11:01:52 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2015-09-10 11:01:52 - ChatSecure] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

That means I arrived to the limit of methods allowed.

So my question is:

Can I do this multipart upload using one unique library, or in a different way? I read a little that I can do it with Retrofit, but I didn't find any (good) example for me. (I'm not familiarizated with this type of process)

Comment: you want to upload multi large contents right ? I am just clarefying

Comment: Yes, the server is done, but in Android, we are going to take, some pictures, videos, or audio, and then upload it to server. SO I did the method like the solution of the question I posted. But I had to add 3 libraries to make it "work", but I reached the methods limit

Comment: move to `Android Studio`

Comment: Hope I can... but is not in my hands. The Big Boss  don't want to move the project to it.. (tried to convince so many times..buuuuutt... no luck)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the below method to send multiple files with json request...

mImagePath is the arraylist of image paths

```
// Method for sending files using multiparting......
public static String sendJsonWithFile(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<String> mImagePaths, String jsonString, String URL)
{
    Log.e("json", jsonString);
    String res = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        boundary = "--" + boundary;
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    StringBody stringBody = new StringBody(jsonString);

    reqEntity.addPart("formstring", stringBody);

    for (int i = 0; i < mImagePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        String imagePath = mImagePaths.get(i);
        if (mImagePaths != null && mImagePaths.size() > 0)
        {

            byte[] filebytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imagePath));

            ByteArrayBody filebodyImage = new ByteArrayBody(filebytes, "image");
            Log.e("file path=", filebodyImage.toString());

            reqEntity.addPart("image", filebodyImage);

        }

    }

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    res = "UnsupportedEncodingException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    res = "ClientProtocolException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    res = "FileNotFoundException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    res = "IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    res = "Exception";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ArsalImam I'll try it and tell you something

Comment: Just one question, 'jsonString' what is it? I mean, I don't understand where to obtain it, or what represents (sorry, bit newbie in this type of server things)

Comment: Actually brother, this method covers the major functionalities between android and server, you can set jsonString = ""

Comment: m.. im stucked.. is launching this error : 09-10 14:09:28.160: E/AndroidRuntime(11166): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field INSTANCE of type Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; in class Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter; or its superclasses (declaration of 'org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter' appears in /system/framework/ext.jar)

Comment: Its a library issue which you are using....! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111751/entity-returns-error-in-multipartentitybuilder

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution which worked for me with no external HTTPCore and such libs. I was facing issue of 64K methods so have no option left to avoid HTTPCore libraries

```
import java.util.List;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This utility class provides an abstraction layer for sending multipart HTTP
 * POST requests to a web server.
 *
 * @author www.codejava.net
 */
public class MultipartUtility {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes a new HTTP POST request with content type
     * is set to multipart/form-data
     *
     * @param requestURL
     * @param charset
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MultipartUtility(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     *
     * @param name  field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     *
     * @param fieldName  name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     *
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     *
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

USAGE

```
private void uploadMedia() {
        try {

            String charset = "UTF-8";
            File uploadFile1 = new File("/sdcard/myvideo.mp4");
            String requestURL = Data.BASE_URL+Data.URL_UPLOAD_REACTION_TEST;

            MultipartUtility multipart = new MultipartUtility(requestURL, charset);

//            multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
//            multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

            multipart.addFormField("friend_id", "Cool Pictures");
            multipart.addFormField("userid", "Java,upload,Spring");

            multipart.addFilePart("uploadedfile", uploadFile1);

            List<String> response = multipart.finish();

            Log.v("rht", "SERVER REPLIED:");

            for (String line : response) {
                Log.v("rht", "Line : "+line);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

PHP Code to accept upload

```
<?php

    $friend_id = $_REQUEST['friend_id'];
    $userid = $_REQUEST['userid'];

    echo 'friend_id : '.$friend_id. ' userid '.$userid;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], "./uploads/".$_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);

?>
```

Comment: how can i add progress bar in it..?